# Optimize loop in python with two array of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I have two array of dictionaries in Python 3.7 and I need join them using a common key.

```
array_1 = [
    {'address1': 'KR 10 B # 14 - 03', 'id': 6605, 'commune1': 'COMUNA 2'}, 
    {'address1': 'KR 90 # 2 OESTE - 17', 'id': 9565, 'commune1': 'COMUNA 18'}, 
    {'address1': 'CL 72 J # 5 NORTE - 70', 'id': 8493, 'commune1': 'COMUNA 6'}, 
    {'address1': 'PAISAJES DEL CASTILLO CS 29', 'id': 10330, 'commune1': ''}
]

array_2 = [
    {'coddirplaca': 'A', 'id': 9565}, 
    {'coddirplaca': 'B','id': 6605}, 
    {'coddirplaca': 'C','id': 10330}, 
    {'coddirplaca': 'D','id': 8493}
]
```

So, I need get an array like this:

```
array_3 = [
        {'address1': 'KR 10 B # 14 - 03', 'id': 6605, 'commune1': 'COMUNA 2', 'coddirplaca': 'B'}, 
        {'address1': 'KR 90 # 2 OESTE - 17', 'id': 9565, 'commune1': 'COMUNA 18', 'coddirplaca': 'A'}, 
        {'address1': 'CL 72 J # 5 NORTE - 70', 'id': 8493, 'commune1': 'COMUNA 6', 'coddirplaca': 'D'}, 
        {'address1': 'PAISAJES DEL CASTILLO CS 29', 'id': 10330, 'commune1': '', 'coddirplaca': 'C'}
    ]
```

I have this code, which compare one dictionary from `array_1` with all list from `array_2` and working good, however this modify my original array_1:

```
for dict_1 in array_1:
    for index in range(len(array_2)):
        dict_2 = array_2[index]
        if dict_1['id'] == dict_2['id']:
            dict_1['coddirplaca'] = dict_2['coddirplaca'] # I create a new key/value in each dict_2
print(array_1)
```

How Can I optimize this loop?

**Note:** Both, `array_1` and `array_2` have the same length, always.

Comment: Have you considered converting them to pandas dataframes and using its join function?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, In fact, `array_3` will be passed to pandas.Dataframe() in order to get a Dataframe. So do you think is better convert `array_1` and `array_2` to pandas dataframe?

Comment: That will probably make it easier.

Comment: `array_3 = [{**x, **y} for x in array_1 for y in array_2 if y["id"] == x["id"]]`

Comment: As this question was closed I have added my pandas answer to the linked question. In short you can use `pd.DataFrame(array_1).merge(pd.DataFrame(array_2), on=['id']).to_dict('records')` after importing pandas as `pd`. And if you want to keep the dataframe just drop the `.to_dict('records')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array_1 = [
    {'address1': 'KR 10 B # 14 - 03', 'id': 6605, 'commune1': 'COMUNA 2'},
    {'address1': 'KR 90 # 2 OESTE - 17', 'id': 9565, 'commune1': 'COMUNA 18'},
    {'address1': 'CL 72 J # 5 NORTE - 70', 'id': 8493, 'commune1': 'COMUNA 6'},
    {'address1': 'PAISAJES DEL CASTILLO CS 29', 'id': 10330, 'commune1': ''}
]

array_2 = [
    {'coddirplaca': 'A', 'id': 9565},
    {'coddirplaca': 'B','id': 6605},
    {'coddirplaca': 'C','id': 10330},
    {'coddirplaca': 'D','id': 8493}
]

array_3 = {d['id']: d for d in array_1}
for d in array_2:
    array_3[d['id']].update(d)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(list(array_3.values()))
```

Prints:

```
[{'address1': 'KR 10 B # 14 - 03',
  'coddirplaca': 'B',
  'commune1': 'COMUNA 2',
  'id': 6605},
 {'address1': 'KR 90 # 2 OESTE - 17',
  'coddirplaca': 'A',
  'commune1': 'COMUNA 18',
  'id': 9565},
 {'address1': 'CL 72 J # 5 NORTE - 70',
  'coddirplaca': 'D',
  'commune1': 'COMUNA 6',
  'id': 8493},
 {'address1': 'PAISAJES DEL CASTILLO CS 29',
  'coddirplaca': 'C',
  'commune1': '',
  'id': 10330}]
```

Comment: Hi @Andrej , finally I have implemented your answer!, thank you..